How do you set the default browser using persistentPreferredActivities under AMAPI?
I am trying to set the default browser using AMAPI's persistentPreferredActivities.
My setup looks something like this:
    "persistentPreferredActivities": [
        {
            "actions": [
                "android.intent.action.VIEW"
            ],
              "categories": [
                "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE",
                "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
            ],
            "receiverActivity": "com.mybrowser/.BrowserActivity"
        }
]

My "BrowserActivity" is configured to support android.intent.action.VIEW intents.
        <activity
            android:name=".BrowserActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_browser"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

And I can manually set my app as the default browser in Settings.
But if I try to start an activity with an implicit intent to open an http/https URL, it always opens in Chrome.
Is this the correct approach to set the default browser under AMAPI or its there another way to do that?
